# How to update another tab`s state

Tags: tabs, react-native

I have two tabs in side a TabBarIOS.

First tab is offer function to add new item into AsyncStorage

Second tab display all item from AsyncStorage

But when i run my app, after adding a new item from First Tab, navigate to second tab i don`t see page re-render, i will need to do a Command+R then i see my new data.

One way to resolve the issue is to read asyncStorage in shouldComponentUpdate, but notice that shouldComponentUpdate will be called constantly by react. While i want to only force update the UI on demand.

So in react native, what is the right way to update state of another UI component?

sample app:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kAIsj2xDnUMklIQmc0b3NiSVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you able to setup a demo at https://rnplay.org so we can help troubleshoot? My initial thought is to use a flux based architecture, such as redux. But even that may not solve this problem. AsyncStorage is a shared state, so it seems to me your actual problem is how to force a re-render of the second tab once state has changed. So, you might look into componentWillReceiveProps() or even forceUpdate() functions. 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate

Comment: @ChrisGeirman, i will try to setup a demo later today. i thought in theory redux should work, everytime when i save data use AsyncStorage, i dispatch a event while the other tab subscribe the this event and update its tab state.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman, rnplay.org seem not support AsyncStorage api, i create a zip file and share in google drive, you should be able to run it on mac, it is an IOS app  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kAIsj2xDnUMklIQmc0b3NiSVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Excellent, I'll grab it and have a look as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman, notice that if i implement "shouldComponentUpdate", this funciton will get call constantly. it is a good practice to access AsyncStore all the time in shouldComponentUpdate ?

Comment: Ok, sorry took me some time to have a look at this, but I think I know what you need to do. Use the componentWillUpdate() lifecycle event, which gets fired on your appContainer component each time you switch tabs. Manage all sate in this appContainer, then push it down to your addData and dataList containers as props.

Comment: Also look at componentWillReceiveProps(), which may actually be a better fit. The purpose of shouldComponentUpdate() is just to optimize. It returns true or false.

Comment: do you mind create a sample how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'm talking about. You will probably want to refactor this a bit once done, but in general here's how I think this would look in the end. I've still a lot to learn about using the lifecycle functions properly, and I'm not sure you'll need them now that I think about it.

## appContainer.js

I've essentially removed your NavigatorIOS. I think those were a mistake. Instead, I'm replacing them with the components, passing down the data as props, including a callback function for the button press. I've moved the addData function up a level.

```
class AppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedTab: 'data-list',
            dataLen: 0
        }

        AsyncStorage.getItem("all-data")
            .then((data)=>{
                if(!data)
                {
                    data = "[]";
                }

                var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
                this.setState({
                    dataLen : dataObj.length
                });
            });

        this.addData.bind(this);
    }

    addData() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("all-data")
            .then((data)=>{
                if(!data)
                {
                    data = "[]";
                }

                var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
                dataObj.push({
                    val: Date.now()
                });

                AsyncStorage.setItem("all-data", JSON.stringify(dataObj));
                this.setState({
                    dataLen: dataObj.length
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <TabBarIOS style={styles.container}>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                title="Add Data"
                selected={this.state.selectedTab == 'add-data'}
                onPress={()=> this.setState({selectedTab: 'add-data'})}
            >
                <AddData onButtonPress={this.addData} dataLen={this.state.dataLen} />
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                title="Data List"
                selected={this.state.selectedTab == 'data-list'}
                onPress={()=> this.setState({selectedTab: 'data-list'})}
                badge={this.state.dataLen}
            >
                <DataList dataLen={this.state.dataLen} />
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
        </TabBarIOS>
      );
    }
}
```

## addData.js

This will simplify your sub-components significantly...

```
class AddData extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.props.dataLen}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.props.onButtonPress}
                    style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Plus One</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }


}
```

## dataList.js

```
class PlayerList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.props.dataLen}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't see to work.. copy your code and run the app. i don`t see the counter increase

Comment: I forgot to warn you that it wasn't tested. It's an example. Probably needs a tweak.

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I'll try to be more helpful once I get past a dev deadline I'm under for a client.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I may have time in the next couple days.

Comment: yes, i still need help on this. right now i am doing some very expensive work-around, will be good if there is any clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## Use Redux

Have you ever thought about using [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) or something equally?
I had the same problem. Eventually the use of Redux solved it for me.

### Official documentation

I highly recommend you the [official documentation](http://redux.js.org) of Redux.

### Example

I will not try to teach you Redux, since the documentation is already really good. But I will try to outline some parts, to give you an idea how to use Redux. I really can't update your existing app, since it's not a trivial tweak. It wouldn't be really sufficient, if the most changes would be cryptic for you.

In your **action creators** you need to call `AsyncStorage` and use the values in your **reducer** to update your state. The important part is the connection of your components with the Redux store. You have to connect it with the component, which you load via `NavigatorIOS`, since [NavigatorIOS doesn't update when passProps update](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/795).

```
<NavigatorIOS
      initialRoute={{
        component: MyView,
        title: 'My View Title',
      }}
    />

// MyView Component
...
class MyView extends Component {
...
}

// Prepare the information of the global state and only pass the relevant values as `props` to the component.
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { isFetching, isError, lastUpdated } = state.posts;
  const { entities: posts } = state.posts || { entities: {} };

  return {
    posts,
    isFetching,
    isError,
    lastUpdated
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyView);
```